# positioning a background image using css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really new into html/css/javascript and I need some help with a site I'm trying to design.

My URL is this one: http://www.wideconcept.com/test2/test.html

It's a full-page background site, with the background image being responsive. The problem is when the user clicks on the "photos" link, and then on '1': the image that gets displayed on the screen as the new background is not positioned as the original background image, and also the height of page increases (the user can now scroll down).

How can I change the html/css code so that, when the user clicks on the 1st image, to display it in the same way as the background image?

Thanks!

EDIT - To be more specific: My main problem is that when I click the 1st photo link, the image is not displayed in the same position and dimensions as the original background image, even though the css properties for that are the same as the original background css properties.

Comment: Take a look at w3schools, its a site with al kinds of tutorials for starters in Html.  http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Your design doesn't seem to be very beginner designer to me..(looks like a pro designer), So, post your **specific** problem code here in SO, so that we can help you...

Comment: Just like @C-linkNepal said, it doesnt look very beginner designer. Also the css looks like its made by a proffessional. If you are really a beginner its better to learn te basics of html/css/js before making a website like this

Comment: @user123456789987654321 from the write of question, we hope the OP has made the site, but seems the OP has some problem with that, but we couldn't identify the specific problem as the OP isn't telling specifically...

Comment: @C-linkNepal Yes you are right, without the prober information its hard to help him/her

Comment: @user3791587 please re-format your question with specific problem and code otherwise your question would be closed and no-one will help you...

Comment: I think i understand the question, youre asking why the 2nd and 3rd image have a scroll to them and how you can fix them. Am i right

Comment: @user123456789987654321 I can't see the scrollbar...

Comment: @C-linkNepal your right with that, i can't see a scrollbar either but when you click on the 2nd picture it is possble to scroll down.

Comment: Since OP is not responding I'm going to vote for close the question....

Comment: @user123456789987654321 I can't see anywhere...

Comment: @C-linkNepal There ISNT a scollbar, however it is possible to scroll. Click on the Photo's link and then select the 2nd picture. You'll understand what i mean

Comment: It seems that the second and third images do NOT resize. I think thats the problem

Comment: To be more specific: My main problem is that when I click the 1st photo link, the image is not displayed in the same position and dimensions as the original background image, even though the css properties for that are the same as the original background css properties.

Comment: @user123456789987654321 Oh! it's not scrolling in firefox, but I just checked it in chrome and find the problem what you said it's scrolling the image, and I solved the problem, but since OP is not responding to us I can't post an answer...

Comment: Have you tried the awnser by @halbano

Comment: @user3791587 make the question more clear, only halbano thinks he understands the question

Comment: @user3791587 please try my answer, and let me know if that what you're in bug?

Comment: Your INLINE imgs and main background image do not have the same height.. its easiest just to change all imgs to be handled in the same way.. (bg images / inline)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized your design was having some scroll position for the background image( which seems fine in firefox but not in chrome )

To fix the problem:

```
img { //line no. 375
    display: block;
    height: 1px;/*this fixes your bug*/
}
```

Another problem I found is that your div with id `background`, so add the following rule inside #background:

```
#background {
z-index: 1; /* to fix the layer bug*/
}
```

Comment: user3791587 This is the easiest way to fix your problem

Comment: it make things better, but the user can still scroll a bit (in chrome at least), and also the new background images don't scale using the original width/height ration as the original background did.

Comment: the "z-index: 1;" in the #background makes the images not appear (in chrome at least).

Comment: Because the image inside #background-image is still there, and you didn't use dynamically for #background as background-image with javascript which you have to change and this works well, I've tested...

Comment: This is my first question that I involve hours of time to help you, please try to give your effort on changing the background-image with javascript....

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can define the main background in that way:

```
body{

 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: url(assets/bg100.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;

 #Add the browser prefixed CSS:

 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 #And
 background-size: cover;

}
```

And then when the user clicks the photos buttons change the background image url through jQuery/javascript.
For example, using jQuery this should be similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(../images/backgrounds/header-top.jpg)');
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please be specific? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The background problem showed by the user, isn't it?
1st photo click is repositioning the initial background image as well.

Comment: @halbano he isnt trying to close the question, its just not clear what the users problem is.

Comment: To be more specific: My main problem is that when I click the 1st photo link, the image is not displayed in the same position and dimensions as the original background image, even though the css properties for that are the same as the original background css properties.

Comment: Maybe i'm confused, but the problem is clear for me in that case. Is true that the user don't show any possible solution and alternative or something like that.
Also, i think that every problem definition could be more or less clear depending the beholder. You think that, have i to delete my "question"?

Comment: @user3791587 i think that the problem exists because you have two different divs to hold the background image. With the ids "background" and "background-images" in your page.

Answer (score -1):

Just like Halbano said, the problem are the `<div id="background">` and the `<div id="background-image">`

You can fix it by doeing the following:

```
<div id="background background-image"></div>
```

Do this at the `Background` div.

Al of the sudden the image will drop a bit but that is simply fixed with css. Also a Menu with a button will pop-up. Apperantly the manu was there already but i could not see it in Chrome.

Good luck

Comment: Try it, it will show a menu ant the scroll will be gone

Comment: Hold up, i havent said i use the ID multiple times, i've put the background-image id into the same div as the background ID and deleted the id from the div where is was originaly

Comment: what's this so ? id="background background-image"

Comment: We cannot do id="background background-image" !!!! And please try my answer and tell me if that solves the problem what you're seeing as the bug...

Comment: The only reason it works is because the browser is being nice to you. There should not be any spaces in an ID. It's bad and wrong and you have simply no idea of how or where it will break stuff. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @ippi I tought it would work in al browser but it only works in Chrome. Thanks for the article